# Navigation Drawer for Android fail to build

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, navigation-drawer

I get the following errors when I try to build a navigation drawer using visual studio xamarin. I have the android support repository installed using the sdk and also have used nuget to install the xamarin.android.v7, ...v4 etc

any idea what i could have done wrongly or not done which had caused below errors? Thanks

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_scrollFlags' in
>   package 'Leftdrawerlayout.Leftdrawerlayout'
>
> No resource identifier found for attribute 'menu' in package
>   'Leftdrawerlayout.Leftdrawerlayout'

[image: screenshot]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#33B86C"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:menu="@menu/menu" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include the problem code.

Comment: hi Petter, i have included the code. I suspect the error lies in my xml file. my apologies, i am a newbie at coding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`layout_scrollFlags`  attribute belongs to `android.support.design` package. Make sure you reference Xamarin.Android.Support.Design [Nuget package](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamandroidsupportdesign)